# How to import excel data into new workbook?

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to combine multiple excel files into one file. I am able to do that correctly, but the location I want to place the data is running into a small problem.

I want my data to start (paste) at cell A2 under the header row, but since my sheet is formatted as a table with a named range, my data is pasted just below the last line of that blank table. This is the code I'm using to paste the data.

```
Sub CombineFiles()

Dim path As String, ThisWB As String, lngFilecounter As Long
Dim wbDest As Workbook, shtDest As Worksheet, ws As Worksheet
Dim Filename As String, Wkb As Workbook
Dim CopyRng As Range, Dest As Range
Dim RowofCopySheet As Integer

ThisWB = ActiveWorkbook.Name

path = "C:\MyFolder"

RowofCopySheet = 2

Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set shtDest = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Import")
Range("A2").Select
Filename = Dir(path & "\*.xl??", vbNormal)
If Len(Filename) = 0 Then Exit Sub
Do Until Filename = vbNullString
    If Not Filename = ThisWB Then
        Set Wkb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=path & "\" & Filename)
        Set CopyRng = Wkb.Sheets(1).Range(Cells(RowofCopySheet, 1), Cells(Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row, Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column))
        Set Dest = shtDest.Range("A" & shtDest.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1)
        CopyRng.Copy
        Dest.PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
        Dest.PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
        Application.CutCopyMode = False 'Clear Clipboard
        Wkb.Close False
    End If

    Filename = Dir()
Loop
Sheets("Import").Select
Range("A1").Select
End Sub
```

Is there any change I can make to the code or the contents of the cells in the table to allow this to work correctly? Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Please try this after changing range to your requirements. It will paste from A2. Using the clipboard takes time and resources so the best way would be to avoid a copy and paste and just set the values equal to what you want.Though you have mentioned that data transfer is required between separate workbooks but mentioned code for only basic problem, so this code fragment conveys the basic concept for transfer in a situation where there is a named table involved.

```
Sub Normalize()
    Dim CopyFrom As Range

    Set CopyFrom = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A2", [H30])
    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Resize(CopyFrom.Rows.Count).Value = CopyFrom.Value

End Sub
```

Comment: You are right about the clipboard taking up time and resources. This code actually wants to copy data from other sheets in a workbook correct? My code is pulling from multiple files. I'll edit my posting with the full code.

Comment: In the meanwhile please see it works alright in one workbook. Ii is late in night here and tomorrow I shall be able to look into it.